# Swift/iOS - Firebase Remote Config fetch values in App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-remote-config

```
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {
    
    //START OF CONFIGURATION

    static let BANNER_ADS_ON = true
```

**how to implement to change the BANNER_ADS_ON in Firebase Remote Config**

Answer (score 0):

Using **Firebase Remote Config** shouldn't be complex. Please have a read on Firebase's documentation and tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-ios#swift

---

To give you more idea, in your `AppDelegate`, you will do something like this:

```
private func setupRemoteConfig() {
    // Interval 1 day if prod. Otherwise 0.
    let interval: TimeInterval = ENVManager.currentEnv == .production ? (60 * 60 * 24 * 1) : 0
    
    let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
    settings.minimumFetchInterval = interval
    
    let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
    remoteConfig.configSettings = settings
    
    remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: interval) { (status, error) in
        if status == .success {
            print("Config fetched!")
            remoteConfig.activate() { (error) in
                // ...
            }
        } else {
            print("Config not fetched")
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error available.")")
        }
    }
}
```

and then to access your value, in your case it's `BANNER_ADS_ON` or whatever key you want, do it like this:

```
let configData = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()["BANNER_ADS_ON"].stringValue
```

Comment: In my case, I need that value on custom splash. But I received it after that. Is there any way to get the value directly in app delegate, So I can decide which Splash animation to show? I am using SwiftUI.

Comment: You can decide that on the next run then.